# StartSSL just for encrypted data transfer

Tags: ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate

I am developing browser extension, that sends some data from currently browsed page to my backend server. User is aware of it, it is intended.

I don't want to cause any user-data exposure, when the user is e.g. on unsecured wifi. So I just want to ensure, the data and the url goes over the net encrypted and only my backend will see them. 
Do I understand correctly, that any SSL certificate, even free one from StartSSL will do the trick?

What other side effects with free SSL certificate should I consider?
- will the user's http-client trust such a certificate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL certificate will do the trick as long as it can be validated. That means that the root certificate of the certificate chain needs to be within the trusted certificate store of the browser.

Furthermore, the certificate will have to be for the right address (URL), must not be revoked, CRL's and OCSP must be configured correctly etc. etc. In other words, the usual steps required to have your web-service certificate validated must be met.

Comment: Ok, then I just test it. I needed just to be sure, that this is conceptually correct way. Thanks!